CORS Error: Getting error while trying to get info of user email and password for frontend
I have a localhost port 1000 for backend. For frontend, the port was 5173
Now to access form data from backend, I used CORS to request from my server, but it is showing me Error 401: unauthorised, while it is giving me 200 in Postman.
The code where I am using CORS
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5173", credentials: true }));

The error on console log
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

I was expecting to Login and getting the form data as email and password entered by the user.
But the signup gets failed owing to the 401 unauthorised error
Have tried adding headers to cors:
app.use(cors({
                'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'],
                'origin': 'requested link',
                'preflightContinue': true,
                'credentials': true
              }));

Still showing 401 error

CORS is a browser security feature that needs to be supported on the server when making cross-origin requests. Postman doesn't implement CORS which is why no requests ever fail from Postman due to CORS.

Setting credentials: true means the the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials will be configured in the response but you aren't seeing a CORS error either. Have you double checked that the request includes the credentials. You should probably include details of the browser request any some more debugging - Do not post any actual credentials here when you update your question with the extra in

Are you using any authentication mechanism? for ex JWT

Yes, I am using jwt

Make sure you include this key in axios when sending a request from the front-end: withCredentials: true

I am already sending this request
